# How does Proc.new finds the block in this code?

Tags: ruby, search, find, block, proc

I have the following code:

```
def call_block
  Proc.new.call
  my_local_proc = Proc.new { Proc.new.call }
  my_local_proc.call
end

call_block { p 'block' }
```

The output is:

```
block
block
```

Can someone explain to me how Proc.new found the block I passed to call_block?
I guess that Proc.new just searches for the closest block and that it`s implemented entirely in C++.

And I have another question: Can something like this be achieve using only ruby? I mean,
can I write a method such that, if not block has been given, takes the block that was passed to the method calling it. Something like:

```
def bar
  if not block_given?
    #use the block that has been given to the caller
  end
  # some code
end

def foo
  bar
end

foo { :block }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proc.new` will use the method's block if called without one inside a method with one attached. [This is documented behavior](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-c-new).

To find out how YARV does it, let's read the source code. Specifically, the [`proc_new` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/proc.c#L384):

```
block_pointer = rb_vm_control_frame_block_ptr(control_frame_pointer);
```

This line retrieves a pointer to the block associated with the current control frame.

I believe these control frames implement Ruby's stack. We are currently inside the `Proc.new` control frame, so this would retrieve the pointer to the block given to the method.

```
if (block_pointer != NULL) {
    /* block found */
} else {
    /* block not found... */
}
```

If the pointer isn't `NULL`, then `Proc.new` was passed a block explicitly. What if the pointer *is* `NULL`, though?

```
/* block not found... */
control_frame_pointer = RUBY_VM_PREVIOUS_CONTROL_FRAME(control_frame_pointer);
block_pointer = rb_vm_control_frame_block_ptr(control_frame_pointer);
```

We move up on the stack and try to get its block. In other words, we move up to the caller's control frame and try to get its block.

```
if (block_pointer != NULL) {
    if (is_lambda) {
        rb_warn("tried to create Proc object without a block");
    }
} else {
    rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "tried to create Proc object without a block");
}
```

Now, if it's not `NULL`, then we pretty much succeeded. If it's *still* `NULL`, then we can't create a `Proc`, so we raise an `ArgumentError`.

The algorithm boils down to this:

1. See if `Proc.new` was given a block

   1. If so, use it
   2. If not, see if caller was given a block

      1. If so, use it
      2. If not, raise error

---

Source code altered for readability. Visit linked source file on GitHub for the original.

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If `Proc.new` called without a block, it takes the block passed to method(if any) and convert it into a proc object.

If you do not pass any block when you call `foo`, it will raise an `ArgumentError` exception, which is reasonable enough, cause `block_given?` returns false and you try to use `Proc.new` without a block.

As of second question, you can pass a proc through many methods by using `&` notation.

It will transform given block into a proc and you can pass it further:

```
def bar &proc
  proc.call
end

def foo &proc
  bar &proc
end

p foo { :block }
# => :block
```

also, `bar` method can be rewritten like this:

```
def bar
  yield if block_given?
end
```

`yield` will execute given block, so you do not need to explicitly transform it into a proc nor execute it via `call`

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html).

> Creates a new Proc object, bound to the current context. Proc::new may
>   be called without a block only within a method with an attached block,
>   in which case that block is converted to the Proc object.